# If $f'(t)$ only defined on $(0,T]$, is it true $ |f(t)-f(0)| = \left| \int_{0}^{t} f'(s) \:ds \right|$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, continuity

I have $f'(t) = A(f)$ for $t\in(0,T]$ and $f(0)$ is known. Then

$$ |f(t)-f(\tau)| = \left| \int_{\min(t,\tau)}^{\max(t,\tau)} A(f(s))\:ds \right| $$

applies for $t \in (0,T]$. Is it also true that at $\tau = 0$, we have the following?

$$ |f(t)-f(0)| = \left| \int_{0}^{t} A(f(s))\:ds \right| $$

My reasoning is that integral of $f'(t)$ on $(0,b]$ is the same as on $[0,b]$ for any $b \in (0,T]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that it depends if $f$ is continuous or not, as
$$\int_0^tf’(x)\,dx=\lim_{a\to 0} \int_a^tf’(x)\,dx=f(t)-\lim_{a\to 0}f(a)$$
and passing to the limit is only allowed is $f$ is continuous.

A counterexample is
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1& x=0\\0 & x\in(0,1]\end{cases}$$

Comment: But if the function is not specified in the first place (as in ODE problem) so it should be assumed continuous at $t=0$, right? because we want $f(t)$ to evolve smoothly from the initial condition $f(0)$.

Comment: Indeed: in ODE's one typically wants the solution to be continuous. on $[0,t]$ and differentiable on $(0,t]$ as it would be physically awkward to have a jump from the initial conditions.